# How to Disable Docusign Emails from API for create envelope?

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I was reading the guide found [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/embedding) and it talked about how we can disable Docusign from sending emails if we use clientid. However, after using Docusign create envelope api request for composite template and including the client id, the emails are still being sent when we generate the recipient signing url. Below is my JSON contract I sent

```
{
   "emailSubject": "Some Subject",
   "status": "sent",
   "compositeTemplates": [
      {
         "serverTemplates": [
            {
               "sequence": "1",
               "templateId": "SOME ID"
            }
         ],
         "inlineTemplates": [
            {
               "recipients": {
                  "signers": [
                     {
                        "name": "Ashwin Jacob",
                        "email": "admin@ashwinjacob.com",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "clientUserId": "1",
                        "status": "sent",
                        "embeddedRecipientStartURL": "SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN",
                        "roleName": "Advisor"
                     }
                  ],
                  "carbonCopies": null
               },
               "sequence": "1"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "recipients": {
      "signers": [
         {
            "name": "Mailnator Jacob",
            "email": "ashwinjacob@mailinator.com",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "clientUserId": "1",
            "status": "sent",
            "embeddedRecipientStartURL": "SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN",
            "roleName": "Advisor"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Not sure if this is relevant but we are hardcoding the client user id to be 1 every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `embeddedRecipientStartURL` along with `clientUserId` in your `createenvelope` call so DocuSign will send an email. Remove `embeddedRecipientStartURL` from your request then you will not receive any email from DocuSign. Setting `clientUserId` means you want to use embedded signing, for embedded signers DocuSign does not send any initial email by default but if you set `embeddedRecipientStartURL` in the request then you are asking DocuSign to send the initial email for embedded signers as well.